# Moving pawns which are defending the king

Tags: tactics, defense

Is f4 a good move here?

```
 [Title ""] 
 [SetUp "1"]
 [FEN "r2qk1nr/pbp3pp/1p2p/4b/4P/2N/PPP2PPP/R1BQ1RK1 w - - 0 1"]

 1. f4
```

On the one hand, many times you would move like this way to attack some pieces - sometimes to *f3* or to *f4*. On the other hand, I feel that I leave open my king.

What are the disadvantages/advantages of this move?

Comment: Hi! Can you give a concrete position with black pieces too? Whether a move (any move) is good or not depends on the exact position. If we had more detail we could say "1. f4 loses to a tactical trick" or "1. f4 is a great attacking move", but at the moment we cannot say.

Comment: @Bad_Bishop Edited my game.

Comment: Disadvantage: Qh5+ is superior, since it simply wins the e5 bishop...

Comment: Yes, it depends on the position. All chess moves carry some good effects and some bad effects. You have to make a judgement in the specific position and based on a large number of factors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no advantages.

The really big disadvantage is that after:
1. f4 BxN
2. bxB QxQ
3. RxQ Bxe4
you are completely lost, a clear piece down with no compensation whereas after 
1. Qh5+ Kf8 
2. QxB
you would have been a pawn up with a much better position.

Answer (score 2):

Moving f2-f4 will make your King weaker since it opens g1-a7 diagonal as well as weakening control over squares e3 and g3. Advantage of making f2-f4 is that you increase control in center by controlling e5 square, obtain f4-f5 push and take g5 square into control for your Knights.

In your position:

```
 [Title ""] 
 [SetUp "1"]
 [FEN "r2qk1nr/pbp3pp/1p2p/4b/4P/2N/PPP2PPP/R1BQ1RK1 w - - 0 1"]

 1. Qh5+
```

Qd1-h5+ is better, picking up the Bishop on e5.

Further, since black's King is weaker than yours due to missing f-pawn, there is no need for you to weaken your King. Instead, you should keep Queens on board and attack using your pieces.